# Does the word "comparatively" require two operands?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

*Comparatively* is similar to *relatively*.  When using *relatively* it is common that you are comparing against general knowledge or an aforementioned entity(ies).   When using *comparatively*, do you need to include the things getting "compared"?

Comment: It can be implied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of *relatively* and *comparatively* is the same; in both cases, the two 'entities' must either be stated or be obviously inferrable for the sentence to make sense.  Note the definition of [relatively](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/relatively) and [comparatively](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/comparatively):

> In a relative manner; *in comparison with something else* (TFD)
>   Relating to, based on, or involving *comparison*; in a relative manner; by comparison to something else. (TFD)

---

In the following, it's implied that the Democratic presidential field is perceived (by the Democrats) to be stronger than that of the Republicans:

> Most Democratic strategists believe *the Republican presidential field is comparatively weak*. - NYT

---

Here, both entities are identified.

> While growth is relatively weak today, *prices* in financial markets — even if not the housing market — have already rebounded from *their levels*  at the nadir of the financial crisis. - NYT

---

This sentence makes no sense without knowing what *bowling* is being compared to. It's not general knowledge, and must be explained by a preceding sentence.

> It might be argued that the award comes in a period when *bowling is comparatively weak.* - NYT

---

Likewise, this sentence would make no sense without knowing what *Ohio* is being compared to (implied: other states). It must be inferred:

> The A.F.L.-C.I.O. is *relatively weak in Ohio*, and some tensions exist between public and private sector unions. - NYT

---

Here, *relatively* is self-referential:

> Powerful turbines are able to capture power even when *the wind is relatively weak*... NYT